# Database user permissions: GRANT VIEW DEFINITION but DENY on some object types

Tags: sql-server, permissions, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to figure out a combination of permissions that will allow a partner to see basic db schema but not expose objects including code. So,

1. VIEW and SELECT on TABLES (including keys)
2. Prevent/DENY on Views, Stored Procs, Functions.

I've thought about going through and denying on individual objects, but this won't protect any that are newly created.

Added consideration - I need to get this to work in SQL Azure.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a role and then grant / revoke permissions to it. Any user that is a part of the role will inherit the permissions.

Below is an example to get you started :

```
 -- Create the database role
CREATE ROLE TableSelector AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
 ---- Grant access rights to a specific schema in the databas
GRANT 
      SELECT 

ON SCHEMA::dbo
      TO TableSelector 
GO

-- Add an existing user to the new role created 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'TableSelector', 'MyDBUser'
GO

-- Revoke access rights on a schema from a role 
DENY ALTER  -- you can customize here ...
ON SCHEMA::dbo
      TO TableSelector
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you just need an allowed list of objects.  This can be done in a script as below or in the define Role as described by Kin. Below is an example of granting rights to a user using a table variable defining the list of allowed objects.

```
DECLARE @AllowedObjects AS TABLE(
   name SYSNAME
)

INSERT INTO @AllowedObjects
SELECT N'dbo.Table1'
UNION
SELECT N'dbo.Table2'

DECLARE @name SYSNAME
DECLARE names CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM @AllowedObjects
OPEN names
FETCH NEXT FROM names INTO @name
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
  IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -2)
  BEGIN
        EXEC ('GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::' + @name + ' TO userName')
  END
  FETCH NEXT FROM names INTO @name
END
CLOSE names
DEALLOCATE names
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used datareader and datawriter roles to give access to the data. Then granted VIEW DEFINITION with the below proc. Will need to remember to maintain this...

Thanks all.

```
Create PROCEDURE GrantViewDefinitionOnTables  
(@login VARCHAR(30))  
AS  
begin
/* 
Included Object Types are:  
P - Stored Procedure  
V - View  
FN - SQL scalar-function 
TR - Trigger  
IF - SQL inlined table-valued function 
TF - SQL table-valued function 
U - Table (user-defined) 
*/  
SET NOCOUNT ON  

CREATE TABLE #runSQL 
(runSQL VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL)  

--Declare @execSQL varchar(2000), @login varchar(30), @space char (1), @TO char (2)  
DECLARE @execSQL VARCHAR(2000), @space CHAR (1), @TO CHAR (2)  

SET @to = 'TO' 
SET @execSQL = 'Grant View Definition ON '  
SET @login = REPLACE(REPLACE (@login, '[', ''), ']', '') 
SET @login = '[' + @login + ']' 
SET @space = ' ' 

INSERT INTO #runSQL  
SELECT @execSQL + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + [name] + @space + @TO + @space + @login  
FROM sys.all_objects s  
-- Want the view permission to sp, view, trigger then add type code mention in above. eg: where type IN('P','V','FN',TR','IF','TF','U')
WHERE type IN ('U')  
AND is_ms_shipped = 0  
ORDER BY s.type, s.name  

SET @execSQL = ''  

Execute_SQL:  

SET ROWCOUNT 1  

SELECT @execSQL = runSQL FROM #runSQL 

PRINT @execSQL --Comment out if you don't want to see the output 

EXEC (@execSQL) 

DELETE FROM #runSQL WHERE runSQL = @execSQL 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #runSQL)  
   GOTO Execute_SQL  

SET ROWCOUNT 0 

DROP TABLE #runSQL  
end


------------------------

EXEC GrantViewDefinitionOnTables 'MyDatabase'
```

Comment: I would suggest crediting the author of the code: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1593/granting-view-definition-permission-to-a-user-or-role-in-sql-server/